# SOT - limit of finite rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a (separable) Banach space, can we write any bounded operator $T: X\to X$ as a limit in SOT of a *sequence* of finite rank operators? What if $X=l_2$?

Comment: For $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$: yes (if $P_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto the first $n$ terms then $P_n$ converges in SOT to $\Bbb1$ and then $AP_n$ converges to $A$ in SOT for any $A$). For other spaces: no clue, but probably not.

Comment: @s.harp Then probably is true for any space with a basis, for the same reason.

Comment: Its not clear why the projections onto the finite subspace converge in SOT to identity however. Usually that family of projections shouldn't be bounded.

Comment: If it is a basis, aren’t they bounded by the basis constant?